# Is there a way to know when someone pulled from git?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to get a notification or at least see when someone from my team calls git pull on the repo. Is there a way to use some kind of hook to achieve this?

I know we can do it when someone pushes to the repo but how to do it for pull?

Comment: You would have to write some script on the server to notice this. I don't see any usecase why one would do something despite spying on others.

Comment: You may want to describe the problem you are trying to solve with this hook, maybe there is a better way.